# Add Content to Tab Panel With Specific Header Text in Tab Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, tabs

I can create tab panels in tab container dynamically based on options user has selected from Listbox. Let's say there are 4 items in ListBox, 'Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4'. If user selected all 4 items, 4 tab panels will be created in tab container with header text as  'Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4', which is the option name in Listbox.

I would like to add content like chart to tab panel with specific header text. E.g. to add chart only to tab panel with header text 'Item1" only. How can I accomplish this?

This is my codes to create tab panel dynamically:

Aspx file:

```
    <asp:listbox ID="SelectionListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
<asp:listitem>Select All</asp:listitem>
<asp:listitem>Item 1</asp:listitem>
<asp:listitem>Item 2</asp:listitem>
<asp:listitem>Item 3</asp:listitem>
<asp:listitem>Item 4</asp:listitem>
</asp:listbox>

   <div>
         <asp:scriptmanager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:scriptmanager>
    </div>
    <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <contenttemplate>

    <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>
        </contenttemplate>
    </asp:updatepanel>
```

Cs file:

```
protected void RETRIEVE_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
    container.ID = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
    container.EnableViewState = false;
    container.Tabs.Clear();
    container.Height = Unit.Pixel(500);
    container.Width = Unit.Pixel(1200);
    container.Tabs.AddAt(0, GetManualTab());

    foreach (ListItem item in SelectionListBox.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            Label tabContent = new Label();
            tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_";
            tabContent.Text += item.Value;

            AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
            panel.HeaderText += item.Value;
            container.Tabs.Add(panel);
            panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
        }
    }
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
}

public AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel GetManualTab()
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
    return panel;
}
```

**Question:** How to add content like **chart** to tab panel with specific header text. For example: to add chart only to tab panel with **header text 'Item1"**.
Appreciate if someone can help me on this, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

In aspx.cs file you can check the value of the selected item and add chart based on that.

```
    protected void RETRIEVE_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
        container.ID = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
        container.EnableViewState = false;
        container.Tabs.Clear();
        container.Height = Unit.Pixel(500);
        container.Width = Unit.Pixel(1200);
        container.Tabs.AddAt(0, GetManualTab());

        foreach (ListItem item in SelectionListBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {

                Label tabContent = new Label();
                tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_";
                tabContent.Text += item.Value;



                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                panel.HeaderText += item.Value;
                container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);

                if (string.Compare(item.Value,"item 1",true) == 0)
                {
                    ChartArea mainArea;
                    Chart mainChart;
                    Series mainSeries;

                    mainChart = new Chart();
                    mainSeries = new Series("MainSeries");
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(2, 2);
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(3, 3);
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(4, 4);

                    mainChart.Series.Add(mainSeries);
                    mainArea = new ChartArea("MainArea");
                    mainChart.ChartAreas.Add(mainArea);
                    panel.Controls.Add(mainChart);
                }
                if (string.Compare(item.Value,"item 2",true) == 0)
                {
                    ChartArea mainArea;
                    Chart mainChart;
                    Series mainSeries;

                    mainChart = new Chart();
                    mainSeries = new Series("MainSeries");
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(2, 4);
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(3, 6);
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(4, 8);
                    mainSeries.Points.AddXY(6, 1);

                    mainChart.Series.Add(mainSeries);
                    mainArea = new ChartArea("MainArea");
                    mainChart.ChartAreas.Add(mainArea);
                    panel.Controls.Add(mainChart);
                }

            }
        }
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
    }
```

Comment: hi Taleeb, thanks for your help! but I have to add different charts to different tab panels. If I use If statement, charts will only be added to 1 tab panel. Do u know how can I add charts to different specific tab panels?

Comment: you can use if - else if statements.. for example if(string.Compare(item.value, "item 1",true) == 0){//Add chart1} else if(string.Compare(item.value, "item 2",true) == 0){//Add chart2}

Comment: I have to add different charts to many tab panels at 1 go.. if I used this method, it will only add charts to one tab panel? becos once condition is true it will perform the action from there and ignore the other ifelse?

Comment: My bad. Instead of else if you can use multiple if statements... if(string.Compare(item.value, "item 1",true) == 0){//Add chart1}  if(string.Compare(item.value, "item 2",true) == 0){//Add chart2}

Comment: have tried but charts are only added to one tab panel. Once the first if statement is true, it will only execute the first if statement and ignore the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90711/discussion-between-taleeb-and-felicia-soh).

Comment: ok. have tried this but doesn't work :( I need all if statements to be executed. But only 1 is executed.

Comment: Note that there is no else now. Try to debug... put a breakpoint in both the if statements. Is item.value for second loop coming as "item 2" or is it different..? Please note that it would go to second if for the next loop...

Comment: hi my codes looks like this: Label tabContent = new Label();
                    tabContent.ID += item.Value;
                    AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                    panel.HeaderText += item.Text;
                    container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                    panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);

Comment: Continue of code:                     if (tabContent.ID == "002")
                    {
                        panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
                    }
                    if (tabContent.ID == "001")
                    {
                        panel.Controls.Add(Chart2);
                    }

Comment: but only 1 if statement is executed. I want all if statements to be executed. Is it possible or do I have to use javascript? sry I cannot access the chat because of access denied.

Comment: In the code above (in question) you have set tabContent.Id as tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_"; So it will never come as "001" or "002"

Comment: I have changed it to like this:  tabContent.Id as tabContent.ID = += item.Value;    still the same result.

Comment: item.Value (as per the code in OP) is Item 1, Item 2 etc... See, what I'm trying to say is that the code is not being executed because the if statement is failing... If you would put a breakpoint on the line having if statement then when the code reaches the breakpoint you can hover your mouse over tabContent.ID and see what is the value you are getting...

Comment: I've uploaded my solution at the following link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyaj01dm85pyzch/WebApplication1.zip?dl=0. Please refer default.aspx and default.aspx.cs. If you would select item 1 and item 2 and then click on the button you would see that both the charts are becoming visible as is expected.

Comment: hi @Taleeb, I am unable to access the dropbox, sorry do u mind to post your solution here? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It is the same solution - which I've given avove. If you need further assistance on this you will need to edit your question and add the "exact" relevant code